# Transpiling Jasmine spec files to output directory

Tags: typescript, jasmine, systemjs

I have completed the excellent tutorials at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html, including the Tour of Heroes app.

Upon completion, I wanted to move the compiler generated JS to a new build folder. I did this by adding `"outDir": "build"` to file `tsconfig.json`. The desired result was achieved, and my Tour of Heroes app still works.

**Testing is a problem though, as when my NPM transpiles the Jasmine spec files, the following error is displayed:**

```
[1] 16.08.02 22:58:53 404 GET /app/person.spec.js
[1] 16.08.02 22:58:53 404 GET /app/my-uppercase.pipe.spec.js
```

**That is because my compiler generated spec.js and map files are now in the build directory, but not being picked up** (the other application files are picked up when running the app, it is just the test files that are missing). I am not sure how to fix or even where to make the change.

Most likely in my loading of promises in `unit-tests.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Ng App Unit Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- #1. add the system.js library -->
<!-- #1. add the system.js and angular libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    // #2. Import the spec files explicitly
    Promise.all([
        System.import('app/person.spec'),
        System.import('app/my-uppercase.pipe.spec')
    ])

    // #3. wait for all imports to load ...
    //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
    //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
    //     or explain what went wrong.
            .then(window.onload)
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or in the `systemjs.config.js` loader file

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

or perhaps somehow filter out the spec files and not put them in the build folder via the `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "build"
  }
}
```

**Any advice on how to get the Jamsine compiled JS files to be picked up?**

Thanks in advance
X

Comment: Hey @xchagger! I am having the same issue, did you have any luck figuring out what was the issue?